# How can I improve this algorithm to test if all matrix entries are distinct?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This algorithm is to figure out that a matrix is distinct or not.
How can I improve the time complexity of this algorithm?

```
int IsMatrixDistinct(int n, int A[0..n-1,0..n-1])
{
   for int i=0 to n-1 do
      for int j = 0 to n-1 do
         for int k = 0 to n-1 do
            for int m = 0 to n-1 do
               if ( A[i,j] == A[k,m] && !( i==k && j==m) )
                  return 1
   return 0
}
```

Comment: Iterate through every item in the matrix and check whether each item is in a dictionary/hash table. If the item is not, then add it. If it is, then return `false`. If you iterate through the entire matrix, then return `true`.

Comment: A matrix is distinct if both matrix are of order m x n and also both have same elements at (i,j) right ? Then two for loops can do the trick right ?

Comment: @zenwraight In this case, the algorithm is checking whether each value in the matrix is unique.

Comment: Ohh my bad ya got it, so Hashmap would do the trick in O(n^2) time

Comment: Even a set would work.... like if you find any element present in the set then break out there itself ...

Comment: If the language contains a set-type class, then the simplest (but not quickest) algorithm is to just add every item to the set and then check if the set contains `n^2` items.

Comment: @vencott which language are u using for this, I will paste the answer in that language then

Comment: @zenwraight i use C

Comment: @vencott can you paste the whole code in ideone or some online editor and paste it's link, I will edit that code and post the updated logic here ...

Answer (score 2):

Others have already mentioned the use of a hashset. Here is an alternative way that uses sorting:

If your matrix has `M` elements, you can copy the matrix elements to an array of size `M`. You can then sort the array with a sorting algorithm of runtime `O(M log (M))`.

To check for duplicate elements you simply go through the sorted array and check if two adjacent elements are equal which takes `O(M)` time.

The total runtime is `O(M log (M))` . Your original algorithm has a runtime of `O(M²)` .

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)(for python) or [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The time complexity is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

```
int IsMatrixDistinct(int n, int A[0..n-1,0..n-1])
{
    hashTable={}
    for int i=0 to n-1 do
        for int j = 0 to n-1 do
            if A[i,j] in hashTable[A[i,j]]:
                return 1
            else:
                hashTable[A[i,j]]=True
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the time complexity be O(n^2) on expectation if you're using a hash table? Where does the O(log n) term come from?

Comment: @templatetypedef Its updates. My mistake thought avg time of lookup of dict in python is LogN instead it is `O(1)`. Thanks